# Triangle and its circumcircle and collinearity of three points

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

Let the triangle $ABC$ and $A'$, $B'$, and $C'$, the points of intersections of the tangents to its circumcircle at its vertices with the extensions of the sides of the triangle. Show that the three points $A'$, $B'$, and $C'$ are collinear.

[image: Collinearity]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: In your original problem statement, you said that you had trouble drawing the diagram. Now, we have provided your post with a diagram. If you still have difficulty in proving the requested collinearity, you need to tell us. We can definitely help you, if you speak out.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was for last week i figure it out and i solve it! After all i draw the diagram like you did up here. All good, thank you again for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, sry.

Problem wants you to extend the sides AB, AC and BC so that these **extensions** intersect the tangents somewhere out there. You misplaced A', B' and C'.

Comment: I extend the sides in other try but also they are not collinear.